# Trigger.io "Communication with adb failed:"

Tags: android-emulator, trigger.io

I 'm trying to debug my app using Trigger.io to run the app. I am using Windows 8 64bit.  I have tried attaching a device and using an emulator. after running the "Run" button on Trigger it fails with the error "Communication with adb failed:" no additional message is give.  when i look at the debug info I get this:

```
[INFO] Installing apk
[DEBUG] Running: C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb -s emulator-5554 install -r 

c:\users\samuel\appdata\local\temp\tmpgzr3c7
[DEBUG] ADB hung, terminating process
[DEBUG] Running: taskkill /T /IM adb.exe
[DEBUG] EXITO: o processo com PID 3528 (processo filho de PID 1376) foi finalizado.
[DEBUG] EXITO: o processo com PID 7488 (processo filho de PID 2416) foi finalizado.
[DEBUG] EXITO: o processo com PID 1376 (processo filho de PID 1256) foi finalizado.
[DEBUG] Running detached: C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb start-server
[ERROR] Communication with adb failed: 
[ERROR] 
[DEBUG] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\async.py", line 98, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\trigger\api\app.py", line 296, in run
    forge_main.run(['--general.interactive', 'no'])
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\main.py", line 435, in run
    build_to_run=build_to_run,
  File "C:\wamp\www\MultiShow\Trigger\MultiShowApp\.template\generate_dynamic\customer_goals.py", line 143, in run_app
    build_to_run.run()
  File "C:\wamp\www\MultiShow\Trigger\MultiShowApp\.template\generate_dynamic\build.py", line 327, in run
    self._call_with_params(task_method, task_args)
  File "C:\wamp\www\MultiShow\Trigger\MultiShowApp\.template\generate_dynamic\build.py", line 286, in _call_with_params
    return method(self, *params)
  File "C:\wamp\www\MultiShow\Trigger\MultiShowApp\.template\generate_dynamic\android_tasks.py", line 670, in run_android
    interactive=interactive)
  File "C:\wamp\www\MultiShow\Trigger\MultiShowApp\.template\generate_dynamic\lib.py", line 38, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\wamp\www\MultiShow\Trigger\MultiShowApp\.template\generate_dynamic\android_tasks.py", line 706, in run_android
    proc_std = _run_adb([path_info.adb, '-s', chosen_device, 'install', '-r', out_apk_name], 60, path_info)
  File "C:\wamp\www\MultiShow\Trigger\MultiShowApp\.template\generate_dynamic\android_tasks.py", line 95, in _run_adb
    raise AndroidError
AndroidError
```

how can get this running on the emulator? what am i missing?